# How to add publisher in electron builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am new to electron and trying to add publisher in electron builder. But when it creates the installer it says publisher as unknown.

My build obj in package.json is

```
"build": {
    "appId": "app.name",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "iconnewa1.ico"
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "s3",
      "bucket": "bucket_name"
    },
    "mac": {
      "category": "app.category",
      "target": [
        "zip",
        "dmg"
      ]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "perMachine": true
    }
  }
```

Please help me with this. I have search whole documentation to add publisher in electron builder but unable to get any success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use Code Signing to avoid that:

> The regular (and often cheaper) Code Signing Certificate shows a
>   warning during installation that goes away once enough users installed
>   your application and you've built up trust. The EV Certificate has
>   more trust and thus works immediately without any warnings.

https://www.electron.build/code-signing

Comment: But what type of code signing certificate I need?  Like: Bug management, Device Metadata, Report Data, Submissions, WRD – Windows Remote Debugging, LSA e.t.c ? I am not getting it as well

Comment: Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate

Answer (score 0):

Example for Windows :

```
"win": {
  "asar": true,
  "icon": "app/img/icon.ico",
  "legalTrademarks": "(c) 2018 example.com",
  "publisherName": "Example.com",
  "target": [
    "portable"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is not working, Still displaying "Publisher: Unknown".Any other thing we can do for it?

Comment: would appreciate if you can hep me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182226/electron-builder-is-not-bundling-the-python-files