# electron-builder is not bundling the python files

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, electron, electron-builder

This is my directory structure where `renderer.js` is included by `index.html` .
The python scripts `visitor.py` and `download.py` are called from `renderer.js` via [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell).
Once I bundle, it is not able to find the python scripts

```
  |_ index.html
  |_ styles.css
  |_ main.js
  |_ package.json
  |_ dist/
  |_ node_modules/
  |_ renderer.js
  |_ visitor.py
  |_ download.py
```

I tried putting everything in `files: [...]` in `package.json` under `build > files` and then ran `npm run dist`.
I also tried copying python files to `dist` folder explicitly and then ran `npm run dist`.
None are working.

> /Application/test.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/remderer.js:226
>   Error: python: can't open file 'visitor.py': [Error 2] No such file or
>   directory

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.app",
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/",
      "index.html",
      "main.js",
      "package.json",
      "renderer.js",
      "styles.css",
      "visitor.py",
      "download.py"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "squirrel",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "csv-parse": "^2.5.0",
    "electron-css": "^0.6.0",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "python-shell": "^0.5.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^20.19.1"
  }
}
```

PS:
This is the electron-builder I am talking about
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder

Comment: @dev is right you need to user the `extraResources` attribute to write the python files into a external folder. The files inside the asar archive are readonly, so even if you can read the file the pyc cannot be created. Check the asar limitations [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-packaging#archives-are-read-only)

Answer (score 5):

## Please makesure not your typo

`/Application/test.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/remderer.js:226 Error: python: can't open file 'visitor.py': [Error 2] No such file or directory` is **remderer.js**, but other place is **renderer.js**, so please makesure is NOT your typo. If is, correct it.

---

## Reason

Actually `electron-builder` **IS** bundled your python file, but due to `asar`, your `python-shell` can NOT find your python file, so cause the error.

## How to fix

### Solution 1:

Easiest but not recommend by official: **disable asar**

#### How to `disable asar`

change you `package.json` to:

```
{
...
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.app",
...
    "asar": false,
```

then in your `renderer.js`, which contain `python-shell` code, maybe like this:

```js
import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';

PythonShell.run('visitor.py', null, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

should working now.

#### internal logic

after disable asar, the all related file path is not contain asar, become this:

- `/Application/test.app/Contents/Resources/app/visitor.py`
- `/Application/test.app/Contents/Resources/app/renderer.js`

that is, `.app` file structure is:

```
|_ test.app
    |_ Contents
        |_ Resources
            |_ app
                |_ styles.css
                |_ main.js
                |_ package.json
                |_ dist/
                |_ node_modules/
                |_ renderer.js
                |_ visitor.py
                |_ download.py
                ...
```

### Solution 2:

keep enable asar, put extra files into `unpack`:

#### how to asar unpack

change you `package.json` to:

```
{
...
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.app",
...
    "asar": true,
    "asarUnpack": [
      "visitor.py",
      "download.py"
      "renderer.js"
    ],
```

the packaged `.app` file structure is:

```
|_ test.app
    |_ Contents
        |_ Resources
            |_ app.asar             # a single compressed binary file
            |_ app.asar.unpacked    # a folder/directory, contain unpacked origin files
                |_ visitor.py
                |_ download.py
                |_ renderer.js
```

your `renderer.js`, **maybe NOT need change**, and should working.

more details about `asarUnpack` please refer official doc: [Overridable per Platform Options](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#overridable-per-platform-options)

---

PS: some other asar and related trying, can refer my Chinese post: [【已解决】mac中PyInstaller打包后的二进制文件在electron-builder打包后app中有些无法通过child_process的execFile运行](http://www.crifan.com/mac_pyinstaller_packaged_binary_file_electron_builder_app_not_work_by_child_process_execfile)

Comment: I too have the same problem @ishandutta2007 has posted. So the first solution you have mentioned seems to fix the issue because by 'asar:false' you don't let the builder bundle the source code at all. Hence the scripts are located without any issue. The second solution also doesn't seem right[no offense : )] to me because you just exclude those files from bundling. Any user who installs the application can view your scripts. I'm still searching for a sleek solution where I can make my caller point to the bundled python scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify them as follows:

```
    "extraFiles": [
        "from":"source path",
        "to":"your destination"
    ]
```

if you want to put those files by creating directory then use extraResources

```
    "extraResources": [
        "from":"source path",
        "to":"some directory name"
    ]
```

for more info refer
[here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the author for publisher info in your package.json

```
{
"name": "AppName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App description",
  "author": {
    "name": "Publisher Name",  // Enter your publisher Name Here
    "email": "publusher-email-address" // Enter Publisher Email
  }
}
```